# Combine/modify PHP arrays if two values match

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to combine two arrays and subtract a value within the array if two keys match each other.

This is the code I've written so far.

```
$dat = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($cashdrawer_sales) - 1); $i++) {
$obj = $cashdrawer_sales[$i];
foreach ($cashdrawer_refund as $k=>$ref) {
    if ($obj['cash_drawer']==$ref['cash_drawer'] && $ref['department_id']==$obj['department_id']) {
        $cash_drawer_total = $obj['cash_drawer_sale_total'] - $ref['cash_drawer_refund_total'];
        $arr = array('department_id'=>$obj['department_id'], 'cash_drawer' => $obj['cash_drawer'], 'cash_drawer_total' => $cash_drawer_total);
        array_push($dat,$arr);
    } else {
        $cash_drawer_total = $obj['cash_drawer_sale_total'];
        //  echo $cash_drawer_total."<br>";
        $arr = array('department_id'=>$obj['department_id'], 'cash_drawer' => $obj['cash_drawer'], 'cash_drawer_total' => $cash_drawer_total);
        array_push($dat,$arr);
    }
}
}
print_r($dat);
```

Here's an example of the $cashdrawer_sales and $cashdrawer_refund arrays that I'm wanting to manipulate.

cashdrawer_sales

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 64.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 15.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 50.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 193.00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21113
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 30.00
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 10.00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 80.00
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 50.00
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_sale_total] => 125.00
    )

)
```

cashdrawer_refund

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_refund_total] => 103.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_refund_total] => 25.37
    )
)
```

I feel like I'm really close to a solution but I can't get it right

When I run this code I'm getting two amounts for each original value. So (from what I can tell) I am meeting my conditional on multiple passes.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 64.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 64.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 15.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 15.00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 90
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 193.00
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21113
        [cash_drawer_total] => 30.00
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21113
        [cash_drawer_total] => 30.00
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 10.00
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 10.00
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 80.00
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 80.00
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 125.00
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 99.63
    )

)
```

I'm assuming this is happening because I'm iterating through each sale twice to analyze the refund. However, I'm not sure what to do about this.

This is my ultimate goal:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 64.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 15.00
    )


[2] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 80000
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 90
    )


[4] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21113
        [cash_drawer_total] => 30.00
    )


[5] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => 21117
        [cash_drawer_total] => 10.00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => 50502
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 80.00
    )


[7] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => 21112
        [cash_drawer_total] => 50.00
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [department_id] => No Department
        [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
        [cash_drawer_total] => 99.63
    )
)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to separate sale and refund for each cash_drawer?

Comment: I want to subtract the refund total from the corresponding sale total and have a new array with new totals.

Comment: OK, but are you trying to do this job for each cash_drawer? Because your sales array has 7 elements and your refund array has 2 elements.

Comment: yes, I am trying to do this for each cash drawer by department_id (cash_drawer is not unique, deptartment_id is).

Comment: The idea is that a sale total might not have a refund, but if it does have a refund I need to subtract that from the corresponding total and create my new array.

Comment: @AliFarhoudi, I've updated my post with my ultimate goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `department_id` and `cash_drawer` to create result keys:

```
$result = array();

foreach( $cashdrawer_sales as $row )
{
    $key = $row['department_id'].'|'.$row['cash_drawer'];                      # <------
    if( !isset( $result[$key] ) )
    {
        $result[$key] = $row;
        unset( $result[$key]['cash_drawer_sale_total'] );
        $result[$key]['cash_drawer_total'] = 0;
    }
    $result[$key]['cash_drawer_total'] += $row['cash_drawer_sale_total'];
}

foreach( $cashdrawer_refund as $row )
{
    $key = $row['department_id'].'|'.$row['cash_drawer'];                      # <------
    if( !isset( $result[$key] ) )
    {
        $result[$key] = $row;
        unset( $result[$key]['cash_drawer_refund_total'] );
        $result[$key]['cash_drawer_total'] = 0;
    }
    $result[$key]['cash_drawer_total'] -= $row['cash_drawer_refund_total'];
}
```

Then delete keys using `array_values()`:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

This is `$result` now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 80000
            [cash_drawer] => 21112
            [cash_drawer_total] => 64
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 80000
            [cash_drawer] => 21117
            [cash_drawer_total] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 80000
            [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
            [cash_drawer_total] => 50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 50502
            [cash_drawer] => 21112
            [cash_drawer_total] => 90
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 50502
            [cash_drawer] => 21113
            [cash_drawer_total] => 30
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 50502
            [cash_drawer] => 21117
            [cash_drawer_total] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => 50502
            [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
            [cash_drawer_total] => 80
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => No Department
            [cash_drawer] => 21112
            [cash_drawer_total] => 50
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [department_id] => No Department
            [cash_drawer] => No Cash Drawer
            [cash_drawer_total] => 99.63
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 

It's a solution I wouldn't have came to on my own and it is much more logical than what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your code and I think I have what you're looking for...

```
$dat = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($cashdrawer_sales)); $i++) {
    $obj = $cashdrawer_sales[$i];
    foreach ($cashdrawer_refund as $k=>$ref) {
        if ($obj['cash_drawer']==$ref['cash_drawer'] && $ref['department_id']==$obj['department_id']) {
            $cash_drawer_total = $obj['cash_drawer_sale_total'] - $ref['cash_drawer_refund_total'];
            $arr = array('department_id'=>$obj['department_id'], 'cash_drawer' => $obj['cash_drawer'], 'cash_drawer_total' => $cash_drawer_total);
            $dat[] = $arr;
        } else {
            if (!in_array($obj, $dat)) {  // <-- check the array for the item, if it's not there then add it
                $dat[] = $obj;
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($dat as $test){
    print_r($test);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Basically, before adding the current item back to the array, i check to see if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dat = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($cashdrawer_sales) - 1); $i++) {


    $obj = $cashdrawer_sales[$i];
    $match=false; // assume initially that this $obj does not match any $ref till now
    foreach ($cashdrawer_refund as $k=>$ref) {
    //check if this ref matches if yes then break//you are for all obj each time it mathches as well as not matches an obj
         if ($obj['cash_drawer']==$ref['cash_drawer'] && $ref['department_id']==$obj['department_id']) {
              $match=true;
              break;    
         } 
     }
     // this accounts for one obj only once in your output
     if($match){
         $cash_drawer_total = $obj['cash_drawer_sale_total'] - $ref['cash_drawer_refund_total'];
         $arr = array('department_id'=>$obj['department_id'], 'cash_drawer' => $obj['cash_drawer'], 'cash_drawer_total' => $cash_drawer_total);
         array_push($dat,$arr);
     }else{
         $cash_drawer_total = $obj['cash_drawer_sale_total'];
             //  echo $cash_drawer_total."<br>";
         $arr = array('department_id'=>$obj['department_id'], 'cash_drawer' => $obj['cash_drawer'], 'cash_drawer_total' => $cash_drawer_total);
         array_push($dat,$arr);
     }
}
print_r($dat);
```

Comment: I'd also add that this is not the fastest method to do this. You can sort array 1 and array 2 and then employ a better check to complete this in O(n logn) instead of O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

To solve issues like this, the best way is to solve it in your mind or in a paper then implement it.

As i understood, you want to modify sale total for those who have refunds. Then you need check all your sales:

```
foreach ($cashdrawer_sales as $sale_key => $sale) {
}
```

Then we want to check if cash drawer in this department has had a refund. We check all refund:

```
foreach ($cashdrawer_sales as $sale_key => $sale) {
    foreach ($cashdrawer_refund as $refund_key => $refund) {
        if ($sale['cash_drawer'] === $refund['cash_drawer'] && 
                $sale['department_id'] === $refund['department_id']) {
            // and if there was refund then we need to subtract it:
            $cashdrawer_sales[$sale_key]['new_total'] = $sale['cash_drawer_sale_total'] -
                    $refund['cash_drawer_refund_total'];
        }
    }
}
```

This should do the job. Not that to submit changes in the same array, I used key `($cashdrawer_sales[$sale_key]['new_total'])`.

Hope that helps.